# Enable "Do-Not-Track"- Function in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, do-not-track

Is there a way in Selenium (with **Python**) to enable the "Do-Not-Track"-function?

I mean the limitation of a browser (in my case: **Firefox** geckodriver) to retrieve the geolocation of the user.

I know that this is possible and [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6337) is a similar question on GitHub but 1.It's written in JavaScript and 2.It just doesn't work.

Does anyone know a solution?

Here is my code so far:

```
import selenium.webdriver

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)
options = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
options.headless = True
profile.update_preferences()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)

browser.get("https://thesafety.us/check-ip")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I simply have to add the following to my Code:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']["privacy.trackingprotection.enabled"] = True
```

By the way, for example you can also replace `dom.disable_open_during_load` with `media.peerconnection.ice.default_address_only` to disable WebRTC.